# Understanding Newey West corrections and t-values

Tags: time-series, least-squares, autocorrelation, neweywest

I am trying to find if the Japanese market is predictable, using different market valuation variables as independent variables. I use OLS regressions on a time series, because this is done so in previous literature. Due to overlapping observations, I am also calculating the adjusted Newey West (1987) t-values. Suprisingly, I found that the adjusted t-values are more significant (t = -4.62) than the non adjusted ones (t = -0.37). The corresponding adjusted R^2 value is -0.002357. So I am wondering how this can be the case and how this should be interpreted?

My approach with documented SE

```
reg <- lm(return ~ indV, df)
summary(reg)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-138.42   -8.99   -1.64    5.78  478.41 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   2.8871     2.0767    1.39    0.165
Equis        -0.1332     0.3598   -0.37    0.711

Residual standard error: 39.68 on 366 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.0003742, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.002357 
F-statistic: 0.137 on 1 and 366 DF,  p-value: 0.7115
t-val     NW-t-val    adjR^2
-0.37     -4.62       -0.002357

#Newey West comatrix
nw <- NeweyWest (reg, prewhite = FALSE) #set prewhite to false, following 1987 approach

#adjusted t-stats
nreg <- coeftest(reg, vcov=nw)
nreg

t test of coefficients:

             Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.887071   2.149566  1.3431    0.1801    
Equis       -0.133173   0.028801 -4.6239 5.231e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: The finding sounds highly counterintuitive. Overlapping observations imply the effective sample size is smaller than the nominal, so there should be no way of getting a more statistically significant result after accounting for this fact. What are the point estimate and the standard error in each case (vanilla vs. Newey-West)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just edited my question to give insights on the point estimate and standard error. I agree with the findings being counterintuitive, thats why I am so confused how the standard error in the adjusted version can be so much smaller. I don't know if it's relevant, but previous findings also always had lower adjusted t-stats.